# How To Get Android Data From a Bound Service To a Extended Application

Tags: android

I have a class that extends Application, it gets a generated ID from a bound service.

```
public MyApp extends Application
{
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        bindService(intent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        String id = myService.getID();
    }
}
```

My problem is, `id` results to null. How can I get the Id from the service to my application class? I assume, the compiler creates the application before starting the service.

Comment: Can you add your Service class to the question, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle the `onServiveConnected` event on `serviceConnection` object.

Straight from the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html):

> A client can bind to the service by calling bindService(). When it
>   does, it must provide an implementation of ServiceConnection, which
>   monitors the connection with the service. The bindService() method
>   returns immediately without a value, but when the Android system
>   creates the connection between the client and service, it calls
>   onServiceConnected() on the ServiceConnection, to deliver the IBinder
>   that the client can use to communicate with the service.\